# how to use 'sed' in bash to delete a line from a specfic point on?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, bash-scripting, code

so i have these lines for example:

name,lastname,mail@gmail.com

name2,lastname2,mail2@gmail.com

i need to delete the 'mail@gmail.com' in every line
essentially i want to make sed do "delete everything from the second comma to the .com" for every line.

i know how the 's/,.*/' works, but how do i specify that it needs to start from the second comma and not the first one?

this is the result i need:
name lastname
name2 lastname2

hope i explained myself clearly, english is not my first language so if needed i'll try to reword my question.

thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `cut -d , -f 1,2` may be enough; or `cut -d , -f 1,2,4-`.This is not an answer because you explicitly requested `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are two different ways you can go about it that can help serve as basis of understanding for regex and sed:**

In this one, there are 3 remembered patterns and only `\1` and `\2` are chosen:

```
sed -r 's/^(.+),(.+),(.+)$/\1,\2/g' my_csv.txt
```

In this one, there are only two remembered patterns with only `\1` chosen (with `\2` having that second comma at the start of it)

```
sed -r 's/^(.+)(,[a-z0-9_-]+@gmail.com)$/\1/g' my_csv.txt
```

The result in both instances are:

```
name,lastname
name2,lastname2
```

Now, it should be said that for completeness, a regex for email has to account for a variety of things (one example can be unicode characters, assuming international characters). The goal here was to demonstrate this is possible (given your example).

Here is [a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/19340379) on a complete regex for email.